# Batched QR decomposition using CUBLAS

Tags: c, cuda, cublas

I have been trying to perform a QR decomposition of many small matrices in parallel with CUDA. 
I therefore used the `cublasDgeqrfBatched` function in Cublas. I couldn't find a working example of the above fuction and I found some ambiguity in the documentation for calling it.
In fact, I tried to test `cublasDgeqrfBatched` on the example in the  Householder reflections section in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) as this same method is being used by `cublasDgeqrfBatched`. The 2 input small matrices are identical and are the following:

```
A= 12 -51   4
   6   167 -68
  -4   24  -41
```

According to the documentation, Aarray is an array of pointers to matrices with dimensions `mxn` and TauArray is an array of pointers to vectors of dimension of at least `max (1, min(m, n).`

`cublasDgeqrfBatched` performs the QR factorization of each `Aarray[i]` for

i =0, ...,batchSize-1

Each matrix `Q[i]` is stored in the lower part of each `Aarray[i]`

I used the following code to call this function:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_paraMeters.h"

#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<assert.h>
#include <cublas.h>
#include "cublas_v2.h"
#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include <helper_cuda.h>


/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main(){

//mxn: size of Array[i]

const int m = 3;
const int n = 3;
double h_A[3*3*2]={12, -51, 4, 6, 167, -68, -4, 24, -41, 12, -51, 4, 6, 167, -68, -4, 24, -41};// two 3x3 identical matrices for test


const int batchSize=2;//2 small matrices 
const int ltau=3; //ltau = max(1,min(m,n))

// --- CUBLAS initialization
    cublasHandle_t cublas_handle;
    cublasStatus_t stat;
    cublasSafeCall(cublasCreate(&cublas_handle));


// --- CUDA batched QR initialization

    double *d_A, *d_TAU;


checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A, m*n*batchSize*sizeof(double)));  
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_TAU, ltau*batchSize*sizeof(double))); 

checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_A,h_A,m*n*batchSize*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

double *d_Aarray[batchSize],*d_TauArray[batchSize];

for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
{ 
    d_Aarray[i] = d_A+ i*m*n;
    d_TauArray[i] = d_TAU + i*ltau;
}

int lda=3;
int info;

stat=cublasDgeqrfBatched(cublas_handle, m, n, d_Aarray, lda, d_TauArray, &info, batchSize);
if (stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) 
    printf("\n cublasDgeqrfBatched failed");


double *A0,*A1;
A0=(double*)malloc(m*n*batchSize*sizeof(double));
A1=(double*)malloc(m*n*sizeof(double));

checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(A0,d_Aarray[0],m*n*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(A1,d_Aarray[1],m*n*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

}
```

But, got an error `"CUDA error batched_QR/kernel.cu:64 code=4(cudaErrorLaunchFailure) "cudaMemcpy(A0,d_Aarray[0],m*n*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)"`

I think there is an error in the use of pointers but I can't  correct it. Where is the problem please?

**Edit:**

to make d_Aarray and d_TauArray device arrays as talonmies proposed, I added the following:

```
     double *d_A, *d_TAU;


checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A, m*n*batchSize*sizeof(*d_A)));  
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_TAU, ltau*batchSize*sizeof(*d_TAU))); 

checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_A,h_A,m*n*batchSize*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(d_TAU, 0, ltau*batchSize* sizeof(*d_TAU)));
```

But always the same error when copying the result back to host.

Comment: If you read the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/#cublas-lt-t-gt-geqrfbatched) you will see that Aarray and TauArray must be device arrays. Yours are not.

Comment: I'm working with `d_Aarray `and `d_TauArray` which are device arrays. I first allocated `d_A `on the decice memory and then copied `h_A `to `d_A,` then I worked with `d_Aarray[i] = d_A+ i*m*n`and `d_TauArray[i] = d_TAU + i*ltau;`

Comment: In your code d_Aarray and d_TauArray are host arrays, not  device arrays. They might contain device pointers, but they are not device arrays.

Comment: You have completely misunderstood my answer. I'll edit it to make is abundantly clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think there is an error in the use of pointers

You are correct. The arrays of device pointers you are passing to `cublasDgeqrfBatched` are host arrays not device arrays:

```
double *d_Aarray[batchSize],*d_TauArray[batchSize];

for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
{ 
    d_Aarray[i] = d_A+ i*m*n;
    d_TauArray[i] = d_TAU + i*ltau;
}
```

You must copy `d_Aarray` and `d_TauArray` to the device and pass the address of the device copies to `cublasDgeqrfBatched` for this to work correctly. Something like this:

```
double *d_Aarray[batchSize],*d_TauArray[batchSize];

for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
{ 
    d_Aarray[i] = d_A+ i*m*n;
    d_TauArray[i] = d_TAU + i*ltau;
}

double ** d_Aarray_, ** d_TauArray_;
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_Aarray_, sizeof(d_Aarray));
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_TauArray_, sizeof(d_TauArray));

cudaMemcpy(d_Aarray_, d_Aarray, sizeof(d_Aarray), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_TauArray_, d_TauArray, sizeof(d_TauArray), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

stat = cublasDgeqrfBatched(cublas_handle, m, n, d_Aarray_, lda, d_TauArray_, &info, batchSize)
```

[disclaimer: written in Browser]

Here `d_Aarray_` and `d_TauArray_` are *device* memory copies of `d_Aarray` and `d_TauArray`.

Comment: I just edited my question, I still get the same error